# json.stringify() multile objects into 1 string

Tags: javascript, json

is it possible?

basically i'm a trying to achieve something like this

```
 JSON.stringify("address=",Obj_address,Obj_city,Obj_state,Obj_zip)
```

after stringify

to become like

```
address= "Address city state zip"
```

in a string like fashion. Reason being is I'm trying to pass this string into my google geocoding url api.

I played around and it so far only 1 parameter can be passed.

Help appreciated and thanks

Comment: why aren't you doing something like `JSON.stringify({address:Obj_address, city:Obj_city, state:Obj_state, zip:Obj_zip});`?

Comment: Your example isn't JSON; JSON uses `:` between names and values, not `=`.

Comment: @david actually, can i then pass the key into api url? im doing google geocoding to get the coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better.

```
var str = 'address="'+[Obj_address,Obj_city,Obj_state,Obj_zip].join(' ')+'"';
```

But you probaby don't need the quotes.

```
var str = 'address='+encodeURIComponent(
    [Obj_address,Obj_city,Obj_state,Obj_zip].join(' '));
```

Or according to the api with a plus separator.

```
var str = 'address='+encodeURIComponent(
    [Obj_address,Obj_city,Obj_state,Obj_zip].join('+'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try like this one

> alert("address=" + JSON.stringify(Obj_address) + " " +
>   JSON.stringify(Obj_city) + " " + JSON.stringify(Obj_state) + " " +
>   JSON.stringify(Obj_zip));